# Tag for "Number of Views"?

Tags: discussion

This question: [Count the number of views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/53870/count-number-of-views-d7) got tagged with [views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views), in the context of, "How many users have viewed this entity".

I changed the tag from [views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views) to [view-count](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/view-count), as [views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views) has a very particular meaning in Drupal-speak.

However, I'm not sure I like [view-count](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/view-count). What should we call it?

Comment: I'd go for [tag:statistics] personally, I think that covers it. But the question does specifically say _"and use that number as a sort criteria in views"_ so I think the Views tag was appropriate to be honest

Comment: Ops, my bad :( Statistics is good, and I reverted the original change.

Answer (score 3):

From reading that question surely it should just be tagged with [statistics](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistics)(posted this as an answer as I'm sure it will solicit discussion).

I also think the [views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views) tag is fine in this case as the asker wants to know how to use their required statistics as sort criteria in Views.

Comment: Yeah, I missed that the use of "Views" in the last sentence actually meant Views, not statistics.

Comment: It was quite difficult to notice that, as the OP didn't write the Views module's name differently from _views_.

Comment: We should ban the word views in questions unless it directly refers to the Views module ;-)